# Ingresar Datos a Diferentes Cuentas y guardar su contenido

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

necesito que me ayuden en algo, estoy haciendo un sistema y en uno de los formularios debo ingresar notas a los estudiantes según el número de cuenta, lo que necesito es que al momento de ingresar una cuenta diferente se guarden los datos solo para esa cuenta estoy trabajando en Sql Server y en Visual Basic. Mi código de guardar es este:

```
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

 cmd.Connection = conexion

 Dim Agregar As String = "INSERT INTO Clases(n_Cuenta, Nombre, codClase, Nota, Cursadas, Promedio)"

Agregar += "VALUES('" & nCuenta.Text & "','" & Nombre.Text & "','" & codClase.Text & "'," & Nota.Text & "," & Cursadas.Text & ",'" & Double.Parse(Nota.Text) & "')"

cmd.CommandText = Agregar

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

MsgBox("Guardado Con Exito")
```

Comment: tu dato nCuenta.Text no te garantiza eso?

Comment: Pero no especificas cual es el problema. ¿No te guarda? ¿Te guarda pero no los datos que deseas? ¿Te da algún error? ¿Qué error? ¿Dónde? ....

Comment: Si me guarda, el nCuenta lo tengo como primaria, exacto, me guarda pero no los datos que deseo, el botón funciona bien, pero, si pongo una cuenta por ejemplo: 41611089 le guardo las clases y excelente me saca el promedio y clases cursadas, pero, si pongo otra cuenta 41567802 no lo hace, y me toma los datos que ya están guardados con la cuenta   41611089, no se si me explico bien

Comment: @Jeffry Estás teniendo un problema con las tablas, a mi parecer, serviría muchísimo que compartas cuales son las estructuras y el mapa de claves-tablas para saber porque al ingresar otro PK te está devolviendo datos que no son. Por otro lado **es peligrosamente vulnerable** el hecho de que estés** concatenando la consulta con los parámetros.** Hay que solucionar eso como primer objetivo, utilizando parámetros del `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Como puedo hacer para que revises eso? @AgustinM. ? De que manera puedo guardar sin utilizar el SqlCommand?

Comment: Para **guardar** debes hacer uso de Parámetros, dichos se pueden escribir en la consulta como `INSERT INTO Clases(n_Cuenta, Nombre, codClase, Nota, Cursadas, Promedio) VALUES (@N_Cuenta, @Nombre, @CodClase ... ` dónde @N_Cuenta, @Nombre son los **nombres de los parámetros**. Luego añades esos parámetros por código, pasando la información de que tipo de campo son, con una sentencia como: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@N_Cuenta", SqlDbType.Int).Value = nCuenta.Text`. De esa forma no concatenas las strings y **proteges de una posible inyección**.

Comment: Para ayudarte a solucionar tu problema aún falta información creo, cuando te refieres a que si colocas otro número de cuenta los demás `TextBox` no se actualizan me da la impresión que no tiene que ver con la consulta.

Comment: @AgustinM. Si yo ingreso 3 clases y 3 notas a la cuenta 41611037 me saca el promedio y las clases cursadas perfectamente, pero, si ingreso otra cuenta 41611040, no me cuenta como nuevo registro si no que me lo actualiza al anterior es decir, al ser un número diferente me debería de guardar que solo tiene una clase agregada pero no, me suma lo de la anterior.

Lo que yo necesito es validar de que al ingresar el mismo numero de cuenta guarde la información, y al momento de ingresar uno DIFERENTE me guarde solo para ese numero de Cuenta

De que manera puedes revisar mi código más a fondo?

Comment: @Jeffry comprendo, por lo que comentas no deberías tener problemas en el ingreso de los datos (que es sobre esta pregunta), me parece que tu problema radica cuando muestras la información, el tipo de consulta, etc. Creo que deberías intentar rastrear mejor tú donde es posible que se encuentre el error para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Ya lo intente, ya probé con una consulta Select y con una Insert, los datos me los guarda como deseo pero el programa no hace lo que realmente quiero, solo quiero validar datos que sean unicamente para un solo numero de cuenta